# Iterating through characters in a python string and summing their values

Tags: python, variables

So I have a very simple task. The [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) problem Names Scores gives us a file with a set of strings(which are names). Now you have to sort these names in the alphabetical order and then compute what is known as a name score for each of these names and sum them all up. The name score calculation is pretty simple. All you have to do is take a name and then sum up the values of the alphabets in the name and then multiply this sum with the position that the name has on the list. Obviously this seems a pretty simple question.

Being a python beginner, I wanted to try this out on python and being a beginner this was the code I wrote out. I did use list comprehensions as well along with a sum, but that gives me the same answer. Here is my code:

```
def name_score(s):
    # print sum((ord(c)-96) for c in s)
    s1 = 0;
    for c in s:
        s1 = s1 + (ord(c) - 96)
        print s1
    return s1
#         print ord(c) - 96

myList = []
f = open('p022_names.txt')

for line in f:
    myList.append(line.lower())

count = 0;
totalSum = 0;
for line in sorted(myList):
    count = count + 1;
    totalSum += (name_score(line) * count)
print totalSum
```

Now the file p022_names.txt contains only one line "colin". So the function name_score("colin") should return 53. Now try whatever I always end up getting the value -33. I am using PyDev on Eclipse. Now here is a curious anomaly. If I just used the list variable and populated it with the value myList = ["colin"] in the code, I get the correct answer. Honestly I don't know what is happening. Can anybody throw some light into what is happening here. There is a similar loop also in the program to calculate totalSum, but that doesn't seem to have an issue.

[EDIT] After the issue was pointed out, I am posting an updated revision of the code which works.

```
def name_score(s):
    return sum((ord(c)-96) for c in s)


with open('p022_names.txt') as f:
    myList = f.read().splitlines()

print sum((name_score(line.lower()) * (ind+1)) for ind,line in enumerate(sorted(myList)))
```

Comment: First problem might be that your inputs might be in mixed case; and your `ord(c) - 96` would only be valid for lower case.  Another problem is that you don't seem to be multiplying by the character position.  Perhaps you want to do something more like `for p,c in enumerate(s, 1):`?

Comment: Are you sure you are running the same piece of code? As this same code is giving expected output on my machine.

Comment: anmol, You're using all lowercase for your input?

Comment: @JimDennis `myList.append(line.lower())` is converting the all the mixed case to lower.

Comment: Your line will have a newline at the end which has `ord` of `10` which will give you `-86`.

Comment: Thanks @PeterWood. This was something I should have noticed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @anmol_uppal I just figured out the answer and I have just posted the updated code as an edit.

Comment: @JimDennis Given the current problem I don't think there is any need to worry about upper case or lower case. All I wanted was to map alphabet 'a' or 'A' to 1, 'b' or 'B' to 2 and so on until 'z'. Also the position here is the position in the sorted list. The count when iterating does give the value. I have posted an updated code where I use the enumerate on the sorted list. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I missed the `.lower()` call in the `myList.apped()` ... and I didn't account for the lack of "chomping."  As for the rest of my comment, I hadn't read the https://projecteuler.net/problem=22 problem directly and misunderstood his summary of the specification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
96 - 53 - 33 = 10
```

That happens because you have a newline character (`"\n"`) in your file, thus your `line` is not `"colin"` but `"colin\n"`.

To get rid of the newline character, multiple approaches could work. Here is an example:

Replace your line:

```
for line in f:
```

with:

```
for line in f.read().splitlines():
```

Comment: Using `f.read().splitlines()` is wasteful. It doesn't matter in this example, where the whole file is one line, but it's not a good habit to teach. Just call `name_score(line.rstrip('\n'))` or similar.

Comment: Changing `myList.append(line.lower())` to `myList.append(line[:-1].lower())` or `myList.append(line.strip().lower())` would also work.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yeah, it probably makes more sense to do it in the `myList.append`, since he's already "postprocessing" the lines there. Although I wouldn't use just plain `strip` if there's any chance the data could contain other whitespace besides the newlines. (I don't know if Euler Project gives "trick questions" like that, but many teachers do—and of course real-life problems do all the time.:)

Comment: @abarnert It depends on how you define "wasteful". For me I'd be happy with `rstrip('\n')` but I'll insist to have the variable `line` precisely named. :)

Comment: @N00bsie My pleasure to help. :)

Comment: @starrify: Reading an entire file into a temporary string and then into a temporary list when all you needed was to iterate the lines one by one is wasteful. Again, it doesn't _matter_ in this case, because you're only wasting a 6-character string and a 1-element list, but it's still a bad habit. Meanwhile, if `line` is a precise enough name for both `for line in f:` and `for line in f.read().splitlines()`, why isn't it a precise enough name for either the thing you call `rstrip` on in my version, or the thing you get from the second loop after `rstrip` in TigerhawkT3's better version?

Comment: @abarnert The reason there is another list is because the original list of names has to be sorted. Obviously this is not the most elegant code as I was looking to just get the answer and start solving problems in Python. Now I am not sure if I could really avoid creating a temporary list as I do really need a sorted list.

Answer (score -3):

Could it be because you didn't close the file?  As in `f.close()`?

Comment: File will close when the script is done if its missing. just good practice to close it manually

Comment: That's definitely not the issue here.  It's a problem that should be fixed, but not related.

Comment: Also, if you want good practice, it's better to use a `with` statement than a manual `close` call.